# How do I fix my upside down video, and make it so it is not compressed and choppy

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

I am making a small documentary on blender 2.9 (I think) for history class. While doing this I did not encounter any problems until I added a video from my phone to the script.

Now the video is upside down, and it is extremely compressed and choppy. It doesn't even match the audio because it is so compressed, and I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

(I blurred my face for privacy reasons)

Comment: Your best shot is to reproduce the issue dealing with privacy concerns - a short one minute long video of something moving should be fine. If you get the same problems with that video in Blender, you could share that file and describe how you import it (or also share the .blend file).

Comment: Just a tip from my own experience - when I record videos playing guitar, the camera records at 29.97 fps and that is also the speed you can find in the video file properties. When importing the video into Blender it switches to 29.97 fps because that's what the video is set to. But the audio is actually only synchronized when I set the playback speed to 30 fps. Don't know if this is of any use for you.

Comment: little tip: you are using Blender 2.92 as you can see in the bottom right corner ;)  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbOMU.png

Answer (score 1):

It’s not “compressed,” that is a storage term. The video is “playing at the wrong speed.” This may have to do with frame rates. The video being upside down has more than one explanation since it was from a phone, but you can thankfully fix that quite easily. Check out the clip settings on the right to transform it and flip it over, or use a transform strip to do it. Note that you may have to flip it sideways as well to avoid mirror image effect. Look at those same settings for adjusting the video frame rate, or if all else fails use a speed adjuster strip.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an Apple computer, i assume you are using an iPhone too (since your file extension gives a hint to that). If not, don't waste your time with further reading.
I have the same setup and never got problems with audio/video.
Maybe it would be interesting how you inserted your video from your iPhone to Blender. I usually use Airplay. So in Photos i longpress on the photo -> Share -> Airplay. Then choose your Mac(book). You Mac will "normally" save this in your Downloads folder. This movie you can drag & drop in Blender (you know this, else you wouldn't have a video in Blender).
Audio and Video will work (you can tap space to verify that). But maybe the video is not in the right direction. Fix this easily here:

[image]

You can change rotation (in your case 180) and scale as you need.